# atoi() function returning garbage to terminal STM32, C lang

Tags: c, stm32, uart, hal, atoi

I have some question about atoi() function. I'm trying to convert string data received from HAL_UART_Receive_IT function to integer and next to sent again to terminal. And what I have at the exit it Looks like garbage
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfhyE.jpg)

This is part of my code

```
uint8_t UART_Rx_Data;
----------------------
while (1){
  HAL_UART_Receive_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)&UART_Rx_Data, sizeof(UART_Rx_Data));
}
----------------------
void HAL_UART_RxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart){
  if (huart == &huart2){
    int i = atoi((char *)&UART_Rx_Data);
    HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)i, sizeof(i));
  }
}
```

How to get integer from UART_Rx_Data?

*I really believed that there was a problem with atoi function, because another part of my code looks like

```
if (huart == &huart2){
  unsigned int Left_El = atoi((char*) &UART_Rx_Data);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i <= 4095; i++){
      if(i == Left_El){
        unsigned int ADC_Rx_Data = round((i * (100.0 / 4095.0)) + 25);
          __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim21, TIM_CHANNEL_1, ADC_Rx_Data);
      }
    }
}
```

I need just to receive integer data from UART and add duty cycle to TIM, but it doesn't work. I tried to check why, and when I send throw UART data it turned out that there have garbage.
Now I will try remade by  loop "for" for the reason like mentioned below that atoi waits for "\0"

Comment: `atoi` expects a zero terminated string. You're passing it a pointer to a single `uint8_t`. That won't end well. If you know it is a character between `'0'` and `'9'` then `int i = UART_Rx_Data - '0';` would give you an int that matches that single digit.

Comment: As a side note, `atoi` (family) is one of those functions which should _never_ be used, because it has poor error handling. `strtol` (family) is 100% equivalent except it has well-defined error handling and also support other bases than decimal. So always use `strtol` (family).

Answer (score 1):

This line of your posted code passes the *value* of the variable `i` cast to an *address* to the function `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()`, not the *address* of the *value* contained in `i`:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *)i, sizeof(i));
```

Per [the documentation for `HAL_UART_Transmit_IT()` that I found](https://www.disca.upv.es/aperles/arm_cortex_m3/llibre/st/STM32F439xx_User_Manual/group__uart__exported__functions__group2.html#gaf223f2bcc2f5734f147cc5c626d757b0):

> ...
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> ```
> huart pointer to a UART_HandleTypeDef structure that contains the configuration information for the specified UART module.
>
> pData Pointer to data buffer
>
> Size  Amount of data to be sent
> ```

The second argument - `pData` in the documentation - is a pointer to (or the address of) the data to be sent.

This would match that documentation:

```
HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t *) &i, sizeof(i));
```

Note the addition of the `&` "address-of" operator to `i`.

Comment: Abstracting from the address, sensing binary representation of the integer to the text terminal will not display anything meaningful

Comment: @0___________ Well, OP didn't clearly specify what the data was being sent to, so I assumed the implied intent to send the integer value as 4 bytes of binary data was correct. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @0___________ And interestingly, once you write code like that, that bug is going to be very hard to spot.  When you wrote it you "knew" it was correct code, so when you look at it, it still "looks" correct to your brain.  I think that's why walking away from code problems you can't solve and getting them out of your mind allows you to spot problems you simple couldn't "see" earlier.

Comment: Recipe for disaster: Add as many casts as you can to silence those annoying warnings. Who has invented them? You wite the "correct" code and this bloody compiler does not stop printing rubbish

Answer (score 0):

Your code makes no sense.

You receive **one** byte and then call the function which requires C string. It is undefined behaviour and you will not receive number from the terminal this way.

Then you send the binary representation of the integer to the text terminal (assuming that you have added `&` to the variable). It makes no sense at all.

It is hard to understand what you want to archieve.